# Aling two dodecahedron on their faces

Tags: geometry

I am using blender 2.93.5 and I am using the extra objects plugin to create those dodecahedrons. I want them to align exactly (position and rotation)on one of their faces so that everyone of the five vertices is stacking upon each other on the alignment face. The dodecahedrons are the same size of course.

Tried to follow this tutorial on aligning them: https://cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/blender-tutorial-align-2-faces/ but I can't find the  'transform orientation' section mentioned there as by the looks of it blender is changing the UI every update.

just to get my frustration off: Just did one from 2.93.4 and had to search for the 'face select' button again. I do not have to add, that none of the tutorials I worked with in the past few weeks had remotely the interface from an current version...

Any hints are appreciated ;)

Comment: The tutorial uses 2.74 which was way before the most major update there ever was in Blender. If you ever have troubles finding a button, press F3 and start typing what the button is supposed to do. It'll also tell you the shortcut, so if you can remember that one, you'll never have to search for a button again.

Comment: the Transform Orientation panel is on the middle of the header bar

Comment: Thanks for those hints. The F3 thing should be on every blender wiki in first line in boldest font size 100!
Was not able to find the transform thingi with that, but the second comment had the right hint. Thanks for that as well. Unfortunately it does not work straight out of the box. I guess I'll fiddle around for another 2-3h to get this simple task done...

Comment: you could use a Mirror modifier to align 2 dodecahedron on the same face